# How to use CASE inside SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery, case

I'm using SQL Server. The entire query is much longer and I wish to focus on the part that needs fixing. I have something like this that works:

```
SELECT 
    a, b, ..., g, 
    (SELECT p.name + ' (' + pd.class + ')' 
     FROM person p 
     INNER JOIN person_data pd ON p.personid = pd.personid AND pd.typeid = 1 
     WHERE p.personid = k.contactid) as Person
FROM 
    maindata md
INNER JOIN 
    ........
```

I would like to replace `pd.class` with `CASE` statement like

```
CASE (SELECT ....)
    WHEN 1 THEN ....
    WHEN 2 THEN ....
END
```

I have used such `CASE` statements in the query but they have been separately in the original `SELECT` (see a, b, etc.). How to insert the `CASE` statement inside SELECT that is inside `SELECT`?

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    a, b, ..., g, 
    (SELECT p.name + ' (' + 
        class = (CASE (SELECT .....)
            WHEN 1 THEN ....
            WHEN 2 THEN ....
        END)
     + ')' FROM person p 
    INNER JOIN person_data pd ON p.personid = pd.personid AND pd.typeid = 1 
    WHERE p.personid = k.contactid) as Person
FROM maindata md
INNER JOIN ........
```

Comment: Have you tried [COALESCE](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/coalesce.php)?

Comment: `+ class = ` isn't legal, but `CASE (SELECT ...)` is perfectly legal.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is **not** a statement - it's an **expression** that returns a single, atomic value (like `a+b`) ....

Comment: i think your query will work if you leave out "class = "

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert and GuidoG. That was indeed the problem. Thank you marc_s for clarification.